# Flyway not running migration scripts

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, flyway

I am running `gradle flywayMigrate` and getting this output that doesn't show any errors although it is not running my migration scripts:

```
Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 (MySQL 8.0)
Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.006s)
Current version of schema `userdb`: null
Schema `userdb` is up to date. No migration necessary.
:flywayMigrate (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 1.025 secs.
```

my configuration in gradle is as follows:

```
flyway{
    url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306?&serverTimezone=UTC'
    user = 'root'
    password = 'password'
    schemas = ['userdb']
    locations = ['filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration/']
}
```

and my scripts are in:  F:......\src\main\resources\db\migration\v1__Create_user_table.sql

```
create table USERS (
    ID int not null,
    NAME varchar(100) not null
);
```

can't figure out why it is not carrying out the migration. It did however create the flyway history table.

Comment: is there any entry in flyway history table?

Comment: @GolamMazidSajib: there is the one with install rank 0 and description "<< Flyway Schema Creation >>", which I assume refers to the creation of the default schema

Answer (score 5):

I realized what the problem was. I had to capitalize the 'v' in my scriptname "v1__Create_user_table.sql". Amazing waste of time spent debugging.